# selenium web driver C# ожидание

Tags: c#

надо сделать ожидание пока элемент прогрузится но
выдает ошибку на   dr.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));

```
Невызываемый член "ITimeouts.ImplicitWait" не может использоваться как метод.   WindowsFormsApp1    F:\C#\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs    98  Активный
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего надпись "не может пользоватся как метод" намекает тебе что это параметр и его нужно присваивать вот так:

```
dr.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40);
```

Comment: да, помогло. спасибо!

Comment: там есть галочка возле циферок. Ее нужно нажимать если помогло) Вместо коментариев об этом)